# Send encoded ASN.1 data

Tags: java, c, asn.1

I trie to encode an int and send it to the java server. This is my C code on the client

```
int clientNumber;
    printf("Enter a number :\n  "); 
    scanf("%d",&clientNumber);
    Message01_t *a;
    a->number = clientNumber;
    der_encode(&asn_DEF_Message01, a, 1, 0);


    if( send( to_server_socket, &a, sizeof( a), 0 ) != sizeof( a ) )
    {
        printf( "socket write failed");
        exit( -1 );
    }
```

And this is the java code

```
 BerInputStream bin = receive(5);
            Message01 msg01 = new Message01();
            msg01.decode(bin);
            printMessage(msg01);
```

But I alwayse recive the number 42 on the server !!

Comment: DER encoding and BER receiving? Isn't that the problem?

Comment: @AJeneral I was in the same doubt, but apparently DER is a subset of BER and they are compatible.

Comment: If what you've shown is your actual code, then it has a huge problem. You declare Message01_t *a, but it's not allocated, so a->number is undefined. Apart from an int, what else does your struct contain?